# How to pass ng-model value in radio button from ng-repeat into link function on directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want one of the `Radio Button` to be selected once the page is loaded, from another question on stackoverflow i found that `Radio Button` will be check if the value of the input attribute is equal to the value of model applied on the `Radio Button`. But i am unable to access the model(`$parent.selectedItem`) on `Radio Button` in link function inside child directive. Api i used in example is a placeholder but in realtime i will have a property selected which will be `true/false` which I want to bind to the `$parent.selectedItem`

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', []);

mainApp.factory('myFactory', function ($http) {
    var myFactory = {
        myMethod: function () {
            var promise = $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(function (response) {

                return response.data;

            });
            return promise;
        }
    };
    return myFactory;
});
```

Controller:

```
mainApp.controller('myController', function ($scope, myFactory) {
    myFactory.myMethod().then(function (result) {
        $scope.data = result
    })
});
```

Directives:

```
mainApp.directive('parent', function (myFactory) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: 'parent.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            myFactory.myMethod().then(function (result) {
                scope.Model = result
            })

        }
    }
});
mainApp.directive('child', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            Model: '=ngModel'
        },
        replace: true,
        require: 'ngModel',
        templateUrl: 'child.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            // unable to access scope.selectedItem
            console.log(scope.selectedItem) 
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
   // mainpage.html
   <body ng-app="mainApp"><parent></parent></body>

   //parent.html
     <div><child ng-model = "Model"></child></div>

   //child.html
     <div ng-repeat="item in Model"><input type="radio" name="itemSelected"
     ng-value="item" ng-model="$parent.selectedItem"/>{{item.name}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

when you require `ngModel` in the child directive, what you're basically requiring is its controller, this controller is then injected into your link function as the 4th parameter, in your case the `ctrl` argument.

so right now your ngModel might work, but it is not in your link function because you're expecting it to exist on the scope as `selectedItem`, but on your scope you have declared it as Model (not selectedItem). However, you also have access to the ngModel controller, so you could ask for its value there through its controller: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController.

ex:

```
ctrl.$viewValue
// or
ctrl.$modelValue
//whichever serves your purpose
```